# How can I handle a mouseMiddleDrag event in PythonCard?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, mouse, pythoncard

I would like to use the middle mouse button to drag an image in an application written in Python and using PythonCard/wxPython for the GUI.

The latest version of PythonCard only implements a "left mouse button drag" event and I am trying to modify PythonCard to handle a "middle mouse button drag" as well.

Here is the relevant code from Lib\site-packages\PythonCard\event.py :

```
class MouseMoveEvent(MouseEvent, InsteadOfTypeEvent):
    name = 'mouseMove'
    binding = wx.EVT_MOTION
    id = wx.wxEVT_MOTION

    def translateEventType(self, aWxEvent):
        if aWxEvent.Dragging():
            return MouseDragEvent.id
        else:
            return self.id

class MouseDragEvent(MouseMoveEvent):
    name = 'mouseDrag'
    id = wx.NewEventType()

class MouseMiddleDragEvent(MouseMoveEvent): #My addition
    name = 'mouseMiddleDrag'
    id = wx.NewEventType()
```

My addition does not work. What can I do instead? Is there a specific wxPython method that I could use to bypass PythonCard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the the *mouseDrag* event is active regardless of which button on the mouse is pressed. To filter the middle mouse button, you need to call the *MiddleIsDown()* method from the *MouseEvent*.

```
def on_mouseDrag( self, event ):       
    do_stuff()

    if event.MiddleIsDown():
        do_other_stuff()
```